# How to verify if motoROS was installed correctly

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The motoman_driver tutorial left me hanging after these lines. How would I know if the pseudo-external signal is successful?

> ```
> Rotate the pendant key-switch (upper left of pendant) fully counter-clockwise into TEACH mode.
> ```

```
Upgrade your Security Level to MANAGEMENT
Using the pendant, select [In/OUT]→[PSEUDO INPUT SIG]
Set input #82015 CMD REMOTE SEL to ON
Rotate the pendant key-switch (upper left of pendant) fully clockwise into REMOTE mode.
```

Thanks! I'm referring to this page: http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/indigo/InstallServer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302714/how-to-verify-if-motoros-was-installed-correctly/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-07**:
You tagged this with `HC10`.

Please see [Compatibility with collaborative robots (HC series)](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#Compatibility_with_collaborative_robots_.28HC_series.29). Afaik, MotoROS is as yet not compatible with the collaborative robots of Yaskawa.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2018-09-07**:
I was hoping the next line implied it would work if the Power/Force-Limiting features were disabled:

```
The MotoROS application can be installed, but only after disabling the collaborative features
```

It's fine if it won't work, but we would rather use ROS  ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-07**:
Yes, that is stated in that section, but last time I spoke to @millete he said it was not supported at all at the moment.

Perhaps he can clarify.

Edit: and we should update the docs.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-07**:
Reported: [ros-industrial/motoman/issues/243](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/issues/243).

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2018-09-07**:
I got a strong no on HC10 compatability from Motoman. Will edit the docs.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-08**:
Your actual question has of course still not been addressed.

Perhaps @millete can answer that one as well :)

**Comment by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) on 2018-09-10**:
HC10 is not compatible today. But we have a team actively working on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will know if the Pseudo Input has been activated if the circle next to the description has a solid dark-blue fill. If the signal if off, then the there will be dark-blue outline with a light-blue fill.
[image: image description]

Programmatically, you would be able to determine this when you send motion commands to the robot. If this signal has not been enabled, then the robot will reply with a result of ROS_RESULT_NOT_READY and a subcode of ROS_RESULT_NOT_READY_NOT_REMOTE. Though, this reply code could also indicate that the mode-selector-switch on the pendant has not been rotated fully clockwise into REMOTE mode.

---

Originally posted by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) with karma: 101 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0